# Segmentation Fault while using Primus

Tags: 12.10, bumblebee

I have been trying to use primus for a while, but I couldn't manage to get it work. I have followed these instructions; http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html

Optirun is working pretty nice, however if I try to run primus it fails with a segfault.

```
04:10 ~ $ primusrun glxspheres
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm not sure how can I debug this, and why this is happening.

syslog is not helpful either

```
Dec 21 04:53:47 n56-laptop kernel: [ 3581.385043] glxspheres[7889]: segfault at 0 ip
(null) sp 00007fffda4604a8 error 14 in glxspheres[400000+7000]
```

I'm running ubuntu 12.10 - 64bit.

Thanks for any advice/help on this.

Comment: does optirun runs well & you installed `primus-lib:i386`?

Comment: yes both  `06:18 ~ $ glxspheres` and  `06:18 ~ $ optirun glxspheres` works nicely. I just updated my nvidia driver to 310experimental, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `primusrun` script for nvidia-experimental.

Following are the changes required for bumblbee and primus

`gksu gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`

- on line 22, make sure "Driver=" is set to "nvidia", like this:

  **`Driver=nvidia`**
- change the "KernelDriver=" (on line 47) to "nvidia-experimental-310", like this:

  **`KernelDriver=nvidia-experimental-310`**
- change `LibraryPath=` (on line 51) to `/usr/lib/nvidia-experimental-310:/usr/lib32/nvidia-experimental-310`, so it looks like this:

  **`LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-experimental-310:/usr/lib32/nvidia-experimental-310`**
- change the `XorgModulePath=` (line 54) to `XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-experimental-310/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules` so it looks like this:

  **`XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-experimental-310/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules`**

`gksu gedit /usr/bin/primusrun`

There will be three occurrences of `nvidia-current` , replace them with `nvidia-experimental-310`

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/use-nvidia-experimental-drivers-310.html)

Comment: thanks but I already done this. Actually this error was happening when I even don't have experimental drivers. I have upgraded to 310, and done the changes you mentioned here. Nothing changed still, segfault.

Answer (score -1):

If you have [Astrill](https://www.astrill.com/) installed, try removing it. That fixed the problem of Primus segfaulting, on my system.